# Replacing strings in files with bash sed or a scripting language (TCL, perl)

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, tcl

I have a list of C++ source files, which have the following structure:

```
// A lot of stuff
#include <current/parser/support/base.hpp>
// ...
#include <current/parser/iterators/begin.hpp>
// ...
```

I need to replace lines like

```
#include <current/parser/support/base.hpp>
```

with

```
#include <support_base.hpp>
```

Namely, omit the `current/parser` and replace the separator (`/`) with `_`.
Is this possible to do with bash sed or a scripting language?

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to mention that I want to replace anything like

```
#include <current/parser/*/*/*/*>
```

Anything can go after `current/parser`, and with any depth.

Comment: sed could do it, but you should keep in mind that using those tool(sed/awk...) to "fix" your source codes could bring new problems. it's risky.

Comment: Do you want to replace just those lines containing `current/parser` or all the ones containing any `#include <anypath/last/file.hpp>`?

Comment: Edited. Anything that starts with #include <current/parser...

Comment: So given your current edited example, you want `#include <*_*_*_*>` as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with Tcl:

```
# Open the file for reading
set fin [open filein.c r]
# Open the file to write the output
set fout [open fileout.c w]

# Loop through each line
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    # Check for lines beginning with "^#include <current/parser/"
    #
    # ^ matches the beginning of the line
    # ([^>]*) matches the part after "#include <current/parser/" and stores it
    #    in the variable 'match'

    if {[regexp {^#include <current/parser/([^>]*)>} $line - match]} {
        # the edited line is now built using the match from above after replacing
        #    forward slashes with underscores
        set newline "#include <[string map {/ _} $match]>"
    } else {
        set newline $line
    }
    # Put output to the file
    puts $fout $newline
}

# Close all channels
close $fin
close $fout
```

Output with the provided input:

```
// A lot of stuff
#include <support_base.hpp>
// ...
#include <iterators_begin.hpp>
// ...
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/w8VOeO3M) (I edited the code a bit since I can't have a channel open to read/write in files there)

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
sed -i -e '/#include <current\/parser\/support\/base\.hpp>/{ s|current/parser/||; s|/|_|; }' -- file1 file2 file3
```

Edit:

```
sed -i -e '/#include <current\/parser\/.*>/{ s|current/parser/||; s|/|_|g; }' -- file1 file2 file3
```

Would remove `currrent/parsers/` and replace all `/` with `_`. Example result file:

```
// A lot of stuff
#include <support_base.hpp>
// ...
#include <iterators_begin.hpp>
// ...
```

Some details:

```
/#include <current\/parser\/.*>/  --  Matcher.
s|current/parser/||               --  Deletes `current/parser/` in matched line.
s|/|_|g                           --  Replaces all `/` with `_` in same line.
```

Comment: Very nice approach, I specially like the `{}` block that handles all amount of `/`. Also, a small explanation would help people understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `sed` and `-r` for regular expression:

```
sed -r 's|#include <current/parser/support/base\.hpp>|#include <support_base.hpp>|g' file
```

But using this way could kill your code. So be carefull :)

Comment: Errr but this is quite hardcoded, isn't it? What about `iterators/begin.hpp`?

Comment: Also, some more description as to how it can kill a code would be nice. By the way, `.` in regex matches almost any character. Is it different in sed?

Comment: Thanks for that hint @Jerry, forgot to escape it :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's{^#include <\Kcurrent/parser/([^>]*)}{$1 =~ y|/|_|r}e;' file.cpp
```

Or without regex features greater than perl 5.10

```
perl -i -pe 's{(?<=^#include <)current/parser/([^>]*)}{join "_", split "/", $1}e;' file.cpp
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.